# mysql get last message in conversation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently creating an inbox of private messages and want to show the last message that was either sent or received between each unique user. I currently have this

```
SELECT
 Message.id, Message.from, Message.body, Message.isread, Message.timestamp,
 User.id, User.username,
FROM messages as Message 
 LEFT JOIN users as User ON (Message.from = User.id)
    WHERE Message.id IN
     (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `messages` 
        WHERE `to` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
         OR `from` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
    GROUP BY `from`,`to`)
 ORDER BY Message.id DESC;
```

But it gets both the last sent AND received message, I just want **the** last message that was sent between the current user and any other one and the user that the conversation is with.

```
 `Message`.`id` is auto incremented, indvidual message id.
 `Message`.`from` is the ID of the user the message is from.
 `Message`.`to` is the ID of the user the message us to.
```

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to PHP after all? Is there any PHP code involved that you haven't shared?

Answer (score 1):

understand my answer may come waaay too late, but still. This solved it for me:

```
SELECT id, user_to, user_from, body, msg_time FROM chat
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM chat WHERE user_to=:id OR user_from=:id GROUP BY user_to,user_from) ORDER BY msg_time DESC
```

:id is later on changed to $id var like so (if you use PDO) -

```
        $stmt=$this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, user_to, user_from, body, msg_time FROM chat
            WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM chat WHERE user_to=:id OR user_from=:id GROUP BY user_to,user_from) ORDER BY msg_time DESC");
        $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$id));
        $stmt=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $stmt;
```

Hope this helps to those still looking - it took me quite a time ;) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To find only latest *sent* message by current user, then

Change:

```
WHERE `to` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
OR `from` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
```

To:

```
WHERE `from` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
```

To find *any* of the latest sent or received message, then

Change:

```
WHERE Message.id IN
 (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `messages` 
    WHERE `to` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
     OR `from` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
GROUP BY `from`,`to`)
```

To:

```
WHERE Message.id =
 (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `messages` 
    WHERE `to` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
     OR `from` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
  GROUP BY `from`,`to` ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1)
```

To find only latest *sent* message by *any* user, then

Change:

```
WHERE Message.id IN
  (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `messages` 
     WHERE `to` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
      OR `from` = '.$this->currentUser["id"].'
   GROUP BY `from`,`to`)
```

To:

```
WHERE Message.id IN
  (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `messages` 
   GROUP BY `from`,`to`)
```

Comment: it needs to be the last message that was either sent or received between the two users

Comment: Almost there, but this query now only gets the singular last message, I want to get the last message for ALL users, not just the very last person..

Comment: Then using `where to= ... or from=...` makes no sense. Remove them from your original query

Comment: This is a personal inbox for one user, so I need to have that in there. I need to find the last message in the conversation between this and any other user.

Answer (score 0):

and something simple like this?

```
SELECT Message.id, Message.from, Message.body, Message.isread, Message.timestamp, User.id, User.username,
FROM messages as Message 
 LEFT JOIN users as User ON (Message.from = User.id)
ORDER BY Message.timestamp DESC
Limit 0, 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually more simple. If you are using a usefull timestamp-Format (Where the highest inkremental number is the last one, like the time in ms after UNIX-Time, or the format YYYY-MM-DD) you can do it like that:

```
mysql_query("SELECT
 M.id, M.from, M.body, M.isread, M.timestamp,
 U.id, U.username,
FROM messages M 
LEFT JOIN users U ON (M.from = U.id)
WHERE `to` = $this->currentUser["id"]
 OR `from` = $this->currentUser["id"]
ORDER BY M.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`SELECT m1.* FROM messages 
m1 LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON (m1.from = m2.from AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL;`